# Sort Tagged unanswered questions by posted date or by view count

Tags: feature-request, sorting

I was searching the option to sort tagged unanswered questions by posted date or by view count, but i have not found any option to do this. Is it possible to do this now? if not can we have this feature in upcoming version.

Comment: I think part one of your question is answered by http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bbug%5D%20answers%3a0 and part two can be sort of done with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+answers%3A0+views%3A1000